# An easier way to describe the phrase "people relevant to my current situation"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, meaning-in-context, synonyms

As if I was explaining it to a young child, I'm looking for a relatable way to describe the people that are relevant to my current situation.

For example, the people I am talking about could be the people driving on the same road as I, people in the same cinema/bus stop/building as me or people at the same airport, etc.

One way could be to say that we are doing the same "geographical activity," but this isn't very clear in my opinion.

So my question is, how can I talk about the people that are doing what I am doing in a coherent, concise way?

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with "people relevant to my current situation"?  Or, "people driving on the same road with me"? Etc.

Comment: Is this for a mobile app? As in, "relevant" specifically means "nearby" or "physically proximal" and not the broader meaning of say, "in my age group" or "experts in the applicable fields" or "sharing common interests"? If so, your question could be narrowed down some, and would attract more ... relevant ... answers.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from your description, I might say...

> People participating in the same activity
>
> People involved in the same thing I am doing
>
> People around me/nearby while I am ____________

Otherwise, I would just stick to the exact descriptions you used, if possible: "the people driving on the same road," "people in the same building as me," etc.  Sometimes the best way to solve a grammatical question is to say exactly what you mean rather than trying to be general.

I think we tend to use "relevant" about information, not people.  I don't say "people relevant to my life"; I would say either "people involved in my life" or "people who affect my life."